# Zooming centre image of gallery in Android

Tags: android, gallery, zooming

Please guide me... i want the centre image of gallery zoomed. How can i do that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will take some work. use a relative layout, put the image as layout_width=fill_parent, layout_height=fill_parent (have the image scale as you want) and align the gallery part with the bottom of the screen. Then customize the gallery with your custom theme to make it transparent.

Answer (score 0):

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ImageView>
    <Gallery 
    android:id="@+id/Gallery01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    ></Gallery>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
    public class GalleryView extends Activity {
        Integer[] pics = {
                R.drawable.antartica1,
                R.drawable.antartica2,
                R.drawable.antartica3,
                R.drawable.antartica4,
                R.drawable.antartica5,
                R.drawable.antartica6,
                R.drawable.antartica7,
                R.drawable.antartica8,
                R.drawable.antartica9,
                R.drawable.antartica10
        };
        ImageView imageView;
       // int i=0,j,k;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Gallery ga = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
            ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

            imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
            /*i=ga.getSelectedItemPosition();
            j=ga.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            k=ga.getLastVisiblePosition();*/

            ga.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     imageView.setBackgroundResource(pics[arg2]);

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });


            ga.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                            "You have selected picture " + (arg2+1) + " of Antartica", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //imageView.setImageResource(pics[arg2]);
                    imageView.setBackgroundResource(pics[arg2]);


                }

            });

        }


        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private Context ctx;
            int imageBackground;

            public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
                ctx = c;
                TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
                imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
                ta.recycle();
            }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return pics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);
            iv.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150,120));
            iv.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
            return iv;
        }

    }
}
```